# Google Bookmarks thinks I'm in Portugal

Tags: language, google-bookmarks

I was looking for a convenient way to keep links to web sites between multiple computers on Monday. After a bit of searching, I found out Google offers a service that covers my desires just fine, Google Bookmarks.

Fast forward to today, Wednesday afternoon, I loaded up Google Bookmarks to find this:

[image: My Google "Favoritos"]

Sorry, I don't speak Portuguese. I cacheless-refreshed my gmail tab to make sure something wasn't up with my whole account, and it's fine. Hitting the translate button works...

[image: My Google "Favorites"]

...sort of. It works enough to at least know what's going on. I can work with this, but... It really seems backwards.

**How do I tell Google I don't understand Portuguese in my Bookmarks?**

Comment: Are you using a proxy or VPN? What is your [current geoIP location](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=current+geoIP+location)?

Comment: @iglvzx That site says I am in Akron, Ohio, United States. I also am not (knowingly) using a proxy.

Comment: I've just experienced this with an English website that it thought was in Czech. Perhaps Chrome is broken.

Comment: @ekaj This didn't take place on a mobile connection. Was a cable internet connection.

Comment: Would be helpful if that was stated in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set your default language across all Google products from your Google account. To do this, navigate to [your Google account page](https://www.google.com/settings/general).

> [image: Google Account Page]

You should get a page similar to the above page. Now, just click on the language tab and you should be presented with a list of your preferred languages in their respective order.

> [image: Google Account - Language Page]

Just set your primary language to the one you prefer. You can also add other languages in case your primary language isn't available for a Google product.

Answer (score 3):

Try visiting https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?hl=en ? Adding `hl=??` to Google's URLs will solve the language problems in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well. I think there is a bug on Google's side. 
I am a heavy Google Bookmarks user and on two different occasions Google Bookmarks decided to open the Russian version instead of the English one.

And this although

- all settings in all Google products are set to English,
- no proxy is used,
- I do not live in Russia, I do not speak Russian and I have never been to Russia or used Russian sites.