# Chrome redirecting me to Google China

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

When I am accessing Google sites, Chrome is automatically redirecting me to Google China.  This issue seems to be intermittent - occasionally, Chrome will direct me to the regular Google website.

- I am in California, USA.
- This is not happening in any other browsers.
- This is not happening for any other websites/search engines.
- I have checked my hosts file, and that seems to be fine.

Any suggestions on what this problem could be and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Google Chrome are you using? From my experience over the years, there has been a reoccurring bug with Google/Chrome and mistaken language preference. **Related:** http://superuser.com/questions/428085/google-bookmarks-thinks-im-in-portugal

Answer (score 2):

Try going to [www.google.com/ncr](http://google.com/ncr). This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After searching from Google China, try clicking on the top right corner with a "cog shaped" icon. Select the first option from the drop down menu "搜尋設定" This is the settings. On the left column for the next page select "言語". This is the language tab. From the following drop down menu, select ”英文”. This is English. The blue button at the bottom is to save. If it works, it should revert back to English.

EDIT: To be fair, you might still be on the Chinese one, though after I tried this, I was redirected to the regular http://www.google.com. If it doesn't redirect, you will at least get English even though the address is .hk

(Pictures are listed below, try opening them in a new page since they are hard to see)

[image: Click Settings Here]

[image: Click Language Here]

[image: Click English Here and Save]

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing your history and cookies in Chrome, if the burtek's answer doesn't work for you. Then try going to [www.google.com/ncr](http://google.com/ncr) again and see if it works.